# Why is the border popping in and out of existence? Is this a Bootstrap bug?

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, debugging

I'm working in a project that uses Bootstrap and looks like my colleagues and I had discovered what it seems to be a Bootstrap bug. CSS indicates that both `#search-input` and `.input-group-btn` shouldn't have any borders, and this is applied only at certain resolutions. Could this be a Bootstrap bug?

[Fiddle with the code (it doesn't show the bug for some reason)](https://jsfiddle.net/kn7rgk31/)

[Screen recording of the bug in action for comparison](https://d1ax1i5f2y3x71.cloudfront.net/items/003L0I023X120k1G3Z3N/Screen%20Recording%202017-06-21%20at%2002.30%20p.m..gif?X-CloudApp-Visitor-Id=2772530)

JSX of the React component

```
<div className="landing-search">
    <div className="overlay" onClick={this.props.clearResults}/>
    <div className="input-group">
      <input id="search-input"
             className="search-box form-control"
             type="text"
             name="search"
             placeholder="What are you searching for?"
             onKeyPress={this.props.handleSearch}
             onKeyUp={this.props.handleSpecialKey}
             onKeyDown={this.props.handleNavigation}
             onClick={this.props.resetSearchbox}
             ref="searchBox"/>
      <div className="results text-2">
        <div className={"spinner " + this.props.loading} />
        { this.props.search_suggestions.noResults &&
        <div><span className="no-results">Sorry there are no results.</span></div>
        }
        { this.props.renderResource('tag', 'name') }
        { this.props.renderResource('category', 'slug') }
        { this.props.renderResource('artist', 'slug') }

      </div>
      <div className="input-group-btn categories">
        <button type="button" className="btn btn-default dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown">
          {this.props.category.toUpperCase()} <span className="fa fa-angle-down"/>
        </button>
        <ul className="dropdown-menu">
          {this.renderCategories()}
        </ul>
      </div>
      <div className="input-group-addon search-icon">
        <b><span className="fa fa-search lens" /></b>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
```

SCSS

```
$categories-button-width: 9em;

.landing-search {
  margin: 3em 0;
  display: inline-block;

  .search-box {
    border: none;
    height: 3em;
  }

  .search-icon {
    background-color: $keppel;
    border-color: $keppel;
    color: $alabaster;
  }

  @include screen-md {
    max-width: 70%;
  }

  @include screen-lg {
    max-width: 50%;
  }

  @include screen-xl {
    max-width: 40%;
  }

  .categories {
    text-align: left;
    position: relative;
    color: gray;
    border-left-color: gray;
    border-top: none;
    border-bottom: none;

    span.fa {
      position: absolute;
      top: .5em;
      right: 1.5em;
      font-size: 1.5em;
    }

    .dropdown-menu {
      position: absolute;
      width: $categories-button-width;
      min-width: 0;
      top: 0;
      left: 0;
      right: 0;
      border: none;
      margin: 0;
      padding: 0;
      border-radius: 0;
      box-shadow: none;

      li {
        border: none;
        margin: 0;
        min-width: 0;
        padding: 11px 12px;

        a {
          padding: 0;

          &:hover {
            background: inherit;
          }
        }
      }
    }

    button {
      border-radius: 0;
      border: none;
      width: $categories-button-width;
      text-align: left;
      height: 3em;
      background: white;
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: Could you possibly create a fiddle demoing your problem?

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/kevinio/g91caha1/2/